# Virtual Inheritance - Diamond Issue - What really happens

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

I understand and have read enough about the diamond problem which is solved by virtual inheritance. My question here is

> "What does placing virtual next to a base class that you would be inheriting from actually mean"

```
class A { public: void Foo() {} };
class B : virtual public A {};
class C : virtual public A {};
class D : public B, public C {};
```

I wanted to know if my understanding is correct. In the statement

```
  class D : public B, public C {}
```

The compiler will go over first base class B and notice that its inheriting virtually from  `class A`. The compiler will check if instance of class A is present if not it will create an instance of A that is derived by B . The compiler will then go over class C and notice that it inherits virtually from class A. However since its being inherited virtually by C and an instance of A is already present it wont include a new instance. Thus solving the diamond problem. Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. For excellent explanation on this topic, you may read the book "Inside Object C++ Model" by Lippman.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does virtual inheritance need to be specified in the middle of a diamond hierarchy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166264/why-does-virtual-inheritance-need-to-be-specified-in-the-middle-of-a-diamond-hie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. The D instance will be a composition of a C, a B and a single A instance.

Virtual inheritance means that the instance of the virtual base class is looked up at runtime by the instance of the derived class (through a pointer or offset). This makes it possible for the compiler to use a single shared A instance.

It would be hard to find scenarios where virtual inheritance is reasonable and even in those cases the problem can usually be solved with simpler language features and abstractions.

Comment: There's no "racing" involved -- contructors are always invoked strictly in order bottom up and left to right (so constructing D will always involve first constructing A, then B, then C).  Also, reasonable implementations will store the A base offset in the vtable and won't use any extra memory per instance.

Comment: @ChrisDodd that makes sense, it was quite long ago that I checked this implementation and it actually stored the pointer in the instance. Still even the vtable implementation has its disadvantages, its more lookups in return for more efficient memory usage but it still doesn't make virtual inheritance attractive. On racing I meant that in the implementation I've checked all derived ctors have actually called the ctor of A but only the first call reached its goal. You are right that "racing" may not be the right word here as it sounds as if we had a multithreading related problem here. :-)

Comment: Regarding the "hard to tell scenarios where virtual inheritance is really reasonable": look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711871/forcing-unqualified-names-to-be-dependent-values/) and [this follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319185/is-this-interesting-use-pattern-of-virtual-inheritance-for-method-injection-a) I posted.

Comment: I would take issue with the statement "it  would be hard to find scenarios where virtual inheritance is reasonable". Any time a class implements multiple interfaces, virtual base classes are called for. They're also necessary when using plug-ins. (It is reasonable to say that virtual base classes should not contain any data members, or should not have constructors which take parameters, but there's no reason to avoid virtual bases if the base is an ABC.

Comment: @JamesKanze Multiple inheritance stinks. I prefer restrictive design borrowed from other languages: single inheritance + interfaces. This results in code that is easier to understand/maintain/change. If the design respects the "single inheritance" part then there is no need for virtual inheritance to implement "interface classes".

Comment: @pasztorpisti That's one of the uses of multiple inheritance in C++. The most frequent, probably. But I've used plugins to make the code easier to understand/maintain/change. Like most things (everything?), multiple inheritance can be misused, but it's a powerful tool for cleaner, clearer and more maintainable code when used appropriately.

Comment: @JamesKanze Virtual inheritance has high inherent complexity compared to most other language features that have to be used anyway with or without virtual inheritance - that's why it is usually avoided or misused. I'd rather use the cognitive energy of my team to solve business problems instead of dealing with technical problems and disagreements introduced by exotic design patterns and language features even if this means more lines of code.

A plugin is no different - all I expect from it is a clean plugin interface, the simpler the better, especially when it is a boundary between binaries.

Comment: Virtual inheritance is much less complex than templates, but we use templates regularly.

Comment: @JamesKanze Only a small subset of template features are used regularly. Some use cases like pointers/containers/algorithms are straightforward - those abstractions are extremely simple and beneficial (type safety, encapsulation of memory management, etc) without simpler alternatives so the benefit/cost ratio is high. That's why a useful subset of template features and the related abstractions are present in some other languages. The emphasis is on the complexity of the abstractions and the related cognitive overhead - virtual inheritance loses to alternative solutions in this regard.